# Color code of bar in Google Visualization Column charts

Tags: jquery, google-visualization

I have an application which draws Column charts using Google visualization API.

The API handles the assignment of colors, when we do not specify them in the series.

How can we obtain the color code in the click (or select) event of the selected bar?